# Using VBS to open MS Project file as read only

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am trying to find a quick way to open MS Project files as read-only, preferrably from explorer. I was following the tutorial head to do the same thing from excel using [this tutorial](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/windows-7-context-menu-option-open-as-read-only/e28c9301-4ef0-4c0b-bc32-d92efb7be713?msgId=2ba1502f-50dc-4dd5-ba47-511c897b5bf6) which uses the following code:

```
'-------------------- Open as Read-Only.vbs --------------------
Option Explicit

Dim app 'As Object

Call OpenAsReadOnly

Sub OpenAsReadOnly()
   On Error Resume Next   
   Set app = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
   If IsEmpty(app) Then Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

   With app.Workbooks.Open(WScript.Arguments(0))
      If Not .ReadOnly Then .ChangeFileAccess 3 'xlReadOnly
      app.Visible = True
   End With
End Sub
```

but when I try to modify it for Project like this:

```
'-------------------- Open as Read-Only.vbs --------------------
Option Explicit

Dim app 'As Object

Call OpenAsReadOnly

Sub OpenAsReadOnly()
   On Error Resume Next   
   Set app = GetObject(, "MSProject.Application")
   If IsEmpty(app) Then Set app = CreateObject("MSProject.Application")

   With app.Project.Open(WScript.Arguments(0))
      If Not .ReadOnly Then .ChangeFileAccess 3 'xlReadOnly
      app.Visible = True
   End With
End Sub
```

MS Project flashes open then closes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The method to open MS Project files is `app.FileOpenEx`. The first parameter is the file name and the second is the ReadOnly option. There is no `ChangeFileAccess` method in MS Project.

Try this instead:

```
Dim app    
Set app = GetObject(, "MSProject.Application") 
If IsEmpty(app) Then Set app = CreateObject("MSProject.Application")
app.FileOpenEx(WScript.Arguments(0), True)
```